# Button reverts to pre-programmed pseudo-class colors, CSS

Tags: css

I was able to successfully change the background-color (red) of a button and the color of its text (yellow), but for some reason it reverts to having a blue background and a white colored text.

This is my CSS code:

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: red; 
    color: #ffff00; 
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:link {
    background-color: red; 
    color: #ffff00; 
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: yellow; 
    color: #ffff00; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML for the button and if you're using any third party CSS libraries like Bootstrap, etc.

Comment: The CSS looks good to me. So, I am sure the problem is from styles from elsewhere. So it will be better if you can share a link showing a demo of your problem

Comment: it's working fine, try to post your button code in html

Comment: It was definitely being overwritten, probably by a WP plugin. The `!important` tag took care of it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `!important` at the end of your declarations, like this:

`background-color: yellow`

becomes

`background-color: yellow !important`